# Limit search results to prestashop 1.6

Tags: search, prestashop-1.6

I'm new to prestashop 1.6
I have a lot of products on my website.
When searching for products with keywords that have a large number of results, such as 300 items.
It results in the web loading very slowly.
I want to narrow down the search results so that the website loads faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce workload of search engine you can bypass indexing certain products by
setting their visibility to "None" directly in backoffice.

Keep in mind that this way "invisible" products can only
be reached by knowing their direct URL.

Otherwise you'll need to power-up your MySQL server, or think about some
external search engine service.